# How to encrypt Azure Data Factory with CMK (customer managed key)

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template

**Parameters.json**

```
"parameters": {
    "dataFactoryName": { "type": "string", "metadata": { "description": "Name of the data factory. Name must be globally unique" } },
    "resourceTags": { "type": "object" },
    "diagnosticSettingsStorageAccount": { "type": "string", "metadata": { "description": "Resource ID of the storage account used to store diagnostic logs" } },
    "cmkIdentity": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "vaultBaseUrl": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "keyName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "keyVersion": {
        "type": "string"
    }
},
```

**Template.json**

```
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories",
        "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
        "name": "[parameters('dataFactoryName')]",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "tags": "[parameters('resourceTags')]",
        "identity": {
            "type": "SystemAssigned,UserAssigned",
            "userAssignedIdentities": {"[parameters('cmkIdentity')]": {}}},  
        "properties": {
            "publicNetworkAccess": "Disabled",
            "encryption": {
                "identity": {
                    "userAssignedIdentity": "[parameters('cmkIdentity')]"
                },
                "vaultBaseUrl": "[parameters('vaultBaseUrl')]",
                "keyName": "[parameters('keyName')]",
                "keyVersion": "[parameters('keyVersion')]"
            }
        },
        "dependsOn": ["[resourceId('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces',variables('workspaceName'))]"]
    },
```

I am passing these values in:

cmkIdentity: `"/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourcegroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/test-identity"`

vaultBaseUrl: `https://testkeyvault123.vault.azure.net/`

keyName: `test-key`

keyVersion: `t5dca2a5xxxxx399we5`

The Validation passes and the Data Factory is deployed. I can see the `test-identity` in the Managed Identity section. But when I open the Data Factory's UI and navigate to `Manage` and in `Customer managed key` I don't see anything. All fields are empty, see picture below:
[image]

Provided access policy to `test-identity` to the test key vault. Can't figure out what the problem is.

**UPDATED parameters and template**

**parameters**

```
"parameters": {
    "dataFactoryName": { "type": "string", "metadata": { "description": "Name of the data factory. Name must be globally unique" } },
    "resourceTags": { "type": "object" },
    "diagnosticSettingsStorageAccount": { "type": "string", "metadata": { "description": "Resource ID of the storage account used to store diagnoistic logs" } },
    "cmkIdentity": {
        "type": "object",
        "defaultValue": {
            "/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourcegroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/test-identity": {
            }
        }
    },
    "vaultBaseUrl": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "keyName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "keyVersion": {
        "type": "string"
    }
},
```

**template.json**

```
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories",
        "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
        "name": "[parameters('dataFactoryName')]",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "tags": "[parameters('resourceTags')]",
        "identity": {
            "type": "SystemAssigned,UserAssigned",
            "principalId": "",
            "tenantId": "",
            "userAssignedIdentities": "[parameters('cmkIdentity')]"
        },
        "properties": {
            "publicNetworkAccess": "Disabled",
            "encryption": {
                "identity": {
                    "userAssignedIdentity": "[parameters('cmkIdentity')]"
                },
                "vaultBaseUrl": "[parameters('vaultBaseUrl')]",
                "keyName": "[parameters('keyName')]",
                "keyVersion": "[parameters('keyVersion')]"
            }
        },
        "dependsOn": ["[resourceId('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces',variables('workspaceName'))]"]
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried doing it both the ways via json template and even through portal works fine, just to have another parameter which is object type as below:

**Updated Info :** Please add a new parameter as an `cmkidentity_obj` which is `type: object` and have the other parameter `cmkidentity` as `type: string`
and pass the string in :

```
"encryption": {
                "identity": {
                    "userAssignedIdentity": "[parameters('cmkidentity')]"
                },
                "VaultBaseUrl": "[parameters('dataFactory_properties_encryption_VaultBaseUrl')]",
                "KeyName": "[parameters('dataFactory_properties_encryption_KeyName')]",
                "KeyVersion": "[parameters('dataFactory_properties_encryption_KeyVersion')]"
            }
```

**Parameter- `cmkidentity_obj` abd pass it in below template.json** :

```
"cmkidentity_obj": {
        "type": "object",
        "defaultValue": {
            "/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourcegroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/test-identity": {
            }
        }
    }
```

and then passed this object in my template.json :

```
"identity": {
            "type": "[parameters('dataFactory_identity_type')]",
            "principalId": "",
            "tenantId": "",
            "userAssignedIdentities": "[parameters('cmkidentity_obj')]"
        }
```

This deployed successfully with about any error and was able to view my Customer Managed Key in Azure Data Factory(UI), kindly try the same and see.
[image]

My Template.json:

```
"resources": [
    {
        "name": "[parameters('factoryName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories",
        "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
        "properties": {
            "encryption": {
                "identity": {
                    "userAssignedIdentity": "[parameters('cmkidentity')]"
                },
                "VaultBaseUrl": "[parameters('dataFactory_properties_encryption_VaultBaseUrl')]",
                "KeyName": "[parameters('dataFactory_properties_encryption_KeyName')]",
                "KeyVersion": "[parameters('dataFactory_properties_encryption_KeyVersion')]"
            }
        },
        "dependsOn": [],
        "location": "[parameters('dataFactory_location')]",
        "identity": {
            "type": "[parameters('dataFactory_identity_type')]",
            "principalId": "",
            "tenantId": "",
            "userAssignedIdentities": "[parameters('cmkIdentity_obj')]"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, tried it. But now it throws "InternalServerError". 
```{
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "InternalError",
        "message": "Internal error has occurred."
    }
}```

Comment: @bharath -Could you pls share your modified template of jsons so could help debug the issue

Comment: I have updated it in the post. Please see under - *UPDATED parameters and template*

Comment: Please join: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235333/room-for-ipsitadash-mt-and-bharath

Comment: I have updated my answer please check and let me know if it helps, else you can join the room to have it sorted